# Knowing which variants (or extras) of a python library was installed

Tags: python, pip

There are python libraries that can be installed with a range of [extras, or variants](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-extras).

As an example(*), `dask` can be installed with:

```bash
pip install dask
```

or with some extras dependencies with:

```
pip install dask["complete"]
```

Is there a way to check if these extra were installed, and which one?

(*) Please note that I would like to know the answer for the general case, not for the specific case of `dask`.
A solution requiring knowledge of the specific dependencies that are installed when the extra is called for a specific library would not help.

What I tried was: `pip freeze | grep dask` and `pip show dask`, though both installation provides the same results.

Comment: not a direct answer, but if you put your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file and install them using `pip install -r requirements.txt` then you can just look in the requirements file to know which one was specified and presumably installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize `pip inspect` and the following piece of bash code to look if an extra is installed for a specific package.

Example with `dask[complete]`

```bash
pip inspect | jq '.installed [].metadata | select(.name | contains("dask")).requires_dist[]' | grep "extra == 'complete'"
```

Example output:

```
"dask[array,dataframe,diagnostics,distributed] ; extra == 'complete'"
"pyarrow (>=7.0) ; extra == 'complete'"
"lz4 (>=4.3.2) ; extra == 'complete'"
```

If the output is empty, then the specified extra is not installed. If like in the example above the output isn't empty, the extra was installed.

Edit:

To check if any and which extras are installed, the following bash script can be used:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

output=$(pip inspect | jq '.installed [].metadata | select(.name | contains("pytest")).provides_extra[]')
array=()

while IFS= read -r line; do
    array+=("$line")
done <<< "$output"

for element in "${array[@]}"; do
    specific_extra_output=$(pip inspect | jq '.installed [].metadata | select(.name | contains("dask")).requires_dist»
    [ -n $specific_extra_output ] && echo "$element is installed"
done
```

**Note: This solution only works if no other packages are installed alongside the package you wanna examine. E.g. installing both `pytest` and `requests` will result in a false positive. This means this code works the best when used in a pretty sparse populated virtualenv**

Comment: Unfortunately the result of `pip inspect` has different encoding according to the OS where this is run. Is there any way to make it OS agnostic, for example having an equivalent of `pip inspect` directly called into a python module?